# UICollectionView orientation (Top to bottom v. Left To Right)

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'd like to get this collection view layout:
[image]

The collection view class is also its delegate/data source and the layout delegate. The scrolling direction is horizontal. There are two horizontal sections. The first one with header view (orange). The cells with simple border lines contain labels.

The issue here is the collection orientation is wrong [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y32t.png) (top to bottom instead of left to right). Is there any explicit property that can control this orientation/cell composition?

[image]

Another question is related to the cell borders. Is there any elegant way how the border color/width can be set up using auto layout (subclassing)?

Thank you.

UPDATE:
The key value to play with might be ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout).minimumLineSpacing and assigning a big number to it. But it results in one long row of cells so that the sections are together in one row. It is weird component design when a navigation mode (the scrolling direction) dictates the collection layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout you will be able to layout the cells any way you like.  I use a custom flow layout to display a horizontal scrolling set of cells based on an event start time and duration:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dataSource = self.collectionView.dataSource;
    event = [dataSource eventAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    attributes.frame = [Calculate a frame for the event from its data];
    return attributes;
}
```

Similarly use layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind to define your header position.

I found this reference useful [Custom Collection View Layouts](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html).